# How to return a vector object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, vector, stdvector

I am confused about to return a vector object, So please guide me. Thanks.

**My code:**

```
struct Vector3D
{
    float x, y, z;
};

class Vertex
{
public:
    std::vector<Vector3D> xyz;

    std::vector<Vector3D> Getxyz()
    {
        return xyz; // what it returns? reference or copy of this object.
    }
Vector3D& getVec(int i) 
{ 
    return this->xyz[i]; // is it OK?
}
void addVec(Vector3D p) 
{ 
    this->xyz.push_back(p); 
}

};

void Somefunction()
{
    Vertex* p = new Vertex;
    p->Getxyz().push_back(Vector3D(0,0,0)); // 1. is it valid and correct?
Vector3D vec = p->getVec(0); // 2. is it valid and correct?

}
```

Comment: How could it possibly return the "address of this object"?? The type of the address is a pointer type, and the return type of the function is not a pointer type.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say a reference of the object not address..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not correct. `Getxyz()` returns a temporary. You can `push_back` an element to that temporary, but it won't affect `xyz` because it is merely a *copy* of that object. If you want to be able to mutate `xyz`, you need to return a *reference*:

> ```
> std::vector<Vector3D>& Getxyz();
> ```

Comment: So you mean returning a refference of the object is not a copy of that object and all operations are valid such as p->Getxyz().clear(), p->Getxyz().push_back etc. Actually I just want to return the same object not a copy of that object.

Comment: @furqan Yes, a reference returns the same object. No copying is performed.

Comment: @furqan: It's "return a reference to the object". The phrase "return the same object" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Beta: If you want to get pedantic, you aren't really "returning a reference", either. References don't get moved around. Rather, the function evaluation results in a value (the return value), and that value is either an rvalue or an lvalue, depending on whether the return *type* is an object type or a reference type. But the return *value* is always a value, and values are never references.

Comment: @0x499602D2 then is also ok Vector3D& getVec(int i) { return xyz[i]; }? now may be you can get the idea what I want?

Comment: @furqan That also returns a reference to element at index `i`. It's the same concept.

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes I get it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 I have one more question, how should I add object for push_back. Should I add reference of the object or object itself. What is the most appropriate meth and what mostly people do? For Example:  void addVec(Vector3D p) { xyz.push_back(p); }
 void addVec(Vector3D& p) { xyz.push_back(p); }

Comment: Technically they both do the same thing in terms of `push_back` (it will copy its argument when it's an lvalue and add it to the vector). Regarding whether to take the parameter of `addVec` by value or by reference - you should take it by reference to `const`  (`const T&`) because `push_back` only requires the state of the object. It gets more detailed than this but it's hard to type on a mobile. Lol.